# Catalina's zsh and its .zshrc file

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

I am trying hard to wrap my head around zsh "upgrade" from bash in macOS Catalina. Most of the things are great, actually. However, I cannot figure out why I am experiencing difficulties, like accessing **Anaconda** rather than built in Python despite the fact that I put the path to it:

```
# Anaconda3 2019.10
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

But if I have this too, under **Anaconda**'s path, then the system does not "see" **Anaconda** anymore (I've commented it out, for now):

```
# Local path:
# export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Also, I have some odd line added to **gcc** (again, I commented out the odd line):

```
# Setting gcc compiler
export PATH="/usr/local/gcc-9.2/bin:$PATH"
# export CC="/usr/local/gcc-9.2/bin"
```

With lines commented out things are working now. But can anyone explain what is wrong in them and what, specifically, `export CC` should to on top of the `export PATH` line?

Thanks!

Comment: Which anaconda installation method did you use? (e.g. brew cask, original [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) open source installer etc.)

Comment: I suggest you to remove `Catalina` from your question since this is a more general question about `zsh` and `PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the variable setting you want to achieve are both to be run
once only per session and not for every subshell, you have to place
their initialisation definition within `.zprofile` and not within `.zshrc`.

Here are the fixed version of your settings which should work:

```
# Anaconda3 2019.10
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/anaconda3/bin:${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"
```

Here my explanation is I bet you have 2 versions of `anaconda` the older one being located within `/usr/local/bin`.

```
# Setting gcc compiler
export PATH="/usr/local/gcc-9.2/bin:${PATH}"
export CC="/usr/local/gcc-9.2/bin/gcc"
```

Here my explanation is that the `CC` variable should contain not the `PATH`
where to find `gcc` but the exact pathname of the compiler.

If you want to check the correctness of your modifications, don't exit your session. Just enter in any terminal:

```
. ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanations!

So, essentially, I should `mv` my `.zshrc` to `.zprofile`, right?

Some additional infos:
- I do not have **Anaconda** in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: 1st question: you have to put in `.zprofile` everything to be done just once per session, you have to put in `.zshrc` everything depending of the shell level. For my use of shell I don't use `.zshrc` but this is my case of use.

Comment: 2nd question: then it could be another component used indirectly by anaconda. For example it could be the wrong `python` used which is incompatible with `anaconda`. You could check this particular hypothesis by typing `type python`.

Comment: *2nd Q:* When I uncomment the line above with path to `/usr/bin/` it then gives me the macOS version of Python which is 2.7.x. I wonder why isn't that already removed completely... 

Comment: You are right, this version smells musty of mummies .

Comment: [dan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22003/dan) you've been super-helpful, can you give some sort of wrap-up advice: how/what to set in .zshrc and .zprofile in particular? I can put on what I did if that would be a start. The main thing is that, as it seems, I cannot have `export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"` as this then wipes out my **Anaconda**... 

Comment: Thank you.
3rd question: this could be the title of another question much larger than this simple technical problem.

Comment: 4th question: @striatum : don't use this last line where `/usr/bin` (where is the too old `python`) is before your `anaconda` and more recent `python`. Rather use the line to define `PATH` in this answer. It should work.